# Why getPosts() is called within dispatch parentheses? How dispatch is working here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

```js
export const getPosts = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setPostLoading());
  axios
    .get('/api/posts')
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_POSTS,
        payload: res.data
      })}
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_POSTS,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};
```

```js
export const addLike = id => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post(`/api/posts/like/${id}`)
    .then(res => { 
      dispatch(getPosts())
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

In my project whenever a user click on the like button of a post, `addLike` function will be called with an id of that post.

Comment: It's a _higher-order function_, a function that returns a function.

Comment: I know about higher-order function but still do not get how this works. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: In that case I don't know what to add. There's not much point to it being a HOF, as it takes no parameters to close over, but that's why it's called and the _return value_ is passed to dispatch.

Comment: Just a bit of a pedantic technical correction, neither `getPosts` nor `addLike` are [Higher Order Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), e.g. functions that take one or more functions as arguments and returns a function. They *are* however a form of [Function Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are asking why you have to initially *dispatch* your action, and then again inside the asynchronous action need to *dispatch* further actions.

> How dispatch is working here?

You first dispatch your action "value" to the store by calling the `addLike` action creator and dispatching the returned "value" to the store.

```js
dispatch(addLike("123"));
```

Normally the action creators return an action ***object***, e.g. a Javascript object, with `type` and `payload` properties.

```js
{
  type: "MY_AWESOME_ACTION",
  payload: "This is my awesome payload value!",
}
```

However, `addLike` returns a ***function*** when called, e.g. `addLike("123")` returns:

```js
(dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post(`/api/posts/like/${id}`) // "/api/posts/like/123"
    .then(res => { 
      dispatch(getPosts());
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    );
};
```

In other words, the following two code snippets are the same when evaluated.

```js
dispatch(addLike("123"));
```

```js
dispatch((dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/posts/like/123")
    .then(res => { 
      dispatch(getPosts());
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    );
});
```

Thunks, or asynchronous action creators, return ***functions*** instead of objects. You are dispatching a function to the store.

The Thunk middleware you added to your store when it was created intercepts actions that are functions and waits for them to settle (*i.e. resolve or reject*). The middleware calls this action function and passes the store's `dispatch` function (*and `store.getState` and the Thunk middleware `extraArgument`*) to it so further actions can be dispatched as necessary.

Here's a pretty awesome animation that helps visualize the asynchronous data flow, borrowed from the Redux docs.

[image: thunk]

Example Thunk:

```js
const someAsyncAction = (arg) => (dispatch, getState, extraArgument) => {
  ...
}
```

Notice there are two "dispatch" function locations, one in the UI and the other the internal dispatch the store/middleware pass.

> Why getPosts() is called within dispatch parentheses?

Inside your returned `addLike` action you are using the `dispatch` function that is passed to it from the Thunk middleware to dispatch the other actions to the store, e.g. `dispatch(getPosts());`.

Similarly `getPosts` is another asynchronous action creator, returning a function that will be passed the `dispatch` function from the Thunk middleware.

```js
dispatch(getPosts());
```

Evaluates to

```js
dispatch((dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setPostLoading());
  axios
    .get('/api/posts')
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_POSTS,
        payload: res.data
      })}
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_POSTS,
        payload: null
      })
    );
});
```

- [Redux Fundamentals, Part 6: Async Logic and Data Fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic)